# How to enable join spill in Vertica database?

Tags: database, join, vertica

I need to know how to enable join spill in Vertica 6.0 EE?
Are there any parameter that allows me to do this?
If so please exaplain a bit this process.

Comment: I'm curious: what is a "join spill"?

Comment: In addition, disk space is temporarily required by certain query execution operators, such as hash joins and sorts, in the case when they have to spill to disk. Such operators might be encountered during queries, recovery, refreshing projections, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select set_vertica_options('EE','ENABLE_JOIN_SPILL');
```

But I would only use this with the recommendation of Vertica support/Professional services

Comment: ok , this did the trick !! But were is this parameter stated in the documentation !!! P.S. the documentation is so poor !!!